# Matlab P file opening in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I use Octave and have a Matlab made P file (protected function file). How can I open it, use it with Octave? Are there any method to convert it maybe or get content from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P files are protected, you can't open them, that's the whole point of them. You should still be able to run them in MATLAB, but I'm not sure if they'll work in Octave.